# vue js vue-slider-component how to update props

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to vue js and missing passing components prop.
Trying to make the vue-slider-component [example](https://jsfiddle.net/NightCatSama/9pp3dqkq/) to be vertical.

```
<vue-slider direction=vertical ></vue-slider>
```

and

```
<vue-slider :direction=vertical ></vue-slider>
```

failed, how should I pass props to component in the example?

Edit: 
 Tried what was suggested in comments:

```
<vue-slider direction={vertical} ></vue-slider>
```

and

```
<vue-slider :direction={vertical} ></vue-slider>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the value as string like this:

```
<vue-slider :direction="'vertical'"></vue-slider>
```

See the sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/9pp3dqkq/49/)

```js
new Vue( {
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },

  methods: {
  },
  mounted () {
  },
  components: {
    'vueSlider': window[ 'vue-slider-component' ],
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightcatsama.github.io/vue-slider-component/dist/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <vue-slider :direction="'vertical'" :height="100" :width="6"></vue-slider>
</div>
```

Comment: works like charm & according to documentation the string passing was what I missed!  TY

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're after is the magical

```
#app {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

i'm not sure if this can be done via props... i'm honestly not all that familiar with vue-js so sorry to jump the gun on the answer. =)

to be more concise. Add a custom class to your slider and apply the rotate accordingly (so that you're not rotating you entire app =)

Comment: While I do understand what you wrote there is a support for that already in the [props] (https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component#props) under first row - direction. I was hopping to use that one.

Comment: i did see that when i was looking earlier. i messed with your fiddle and the only way i could make it work was by using css... sorry bout that.

Comment: in react, we use brackets to pass some prop values. try ={true} to your vert prop?

Comment: sorry. direction={vertical}

Comment: i'm on my phone now otherwise i'd give it a go

Comment: TY, didn't worked + updated the question so it will be clear what I  did..

Comment: i'll take another peek tomorrow